# Coerce values with as_hms in R

Tags: r

In R, is there a way to coerce a value (`NA` for example) instead of throwing errors when converting string to `hms` in `as_hms`?

I don't see coerce argument in the document and I'm scratching my head on this.

```
library(hms)
as_hms(c('11:15:00',"12:00","3"))
```

> Error in `abort_lossy_cast()`:
> ! Lossy cast from  to  at position(s) 2, 3
> Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.

Comment: You could use `lubridate::hms` instead of `hms::as_hms` ? But the `lubridate::hms` output is of type Period, not sure if that's what you want.

Comment: Thanks. It seems `hms::hms(lubridate::hms(c('11:15:00',"12:00","3")))` is the workaround.